# Overloaded constructor when creating dashboard

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script

When I want to create a dashboard I have an error message:

> Can not call the overloaded constructor with parameters setDataTable (object) because there are several signatures corresponding manufacturer: DashboardPanelBuilder setDataTable interface (DataTableBuilder) interface DashboardPanelBuilder setDataTable (DataTableSource).

In French:

> Impossible d'appeler le constructeur surchargé setDataTable avec des paramètres (object) car il existe plusieurs signatures de constructeur correspondantes : interface DashboardPanelBuilder setDataTable(DataTableBuilder) interface DashboardPanelBuilder setDataTable(DataTableSource).

I simply copy paste the official [test script](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#skeleton) following code in a html file in spreadsheet script and publish like "web apps". I have the same error message when I directly create a JS script with spreadsheet data.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same problem, unfortunately the test script file google uses for demonstration is not very adaptable to other styles.

The problem is that the instruction '.setDataTable' can expect either of two different arguments, Table or TableBuilder.  When you define the Data Table, you need to ensure the format is consistent for one or the other.  I got mine to work using the format:

var dataTable = Charts.newDataTable()
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.DATE,"DATE")
...
  dataTable.build();

var lineChart = Charts.newLineChart()
    .setDataTable(dataTable);

It's an error constructing the Data Table, not in setting the data table, no matter what the error tells you.